# Invalidate session, how to use correctly?

Tags: session, coldfusion

When do you call `getPageContext().getSession().invalidate()`?

I tried calling that at the logout page, then cflocation it back to the main page, and it throws exception.

How to assign a new session right after?

The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7cb3) says:

> You cannot destroy the session and
>   create a session on the same request,
>   as creating a new session involves
>   sending session cookies back.sending session cookies back.

I thought cflocation to the main page already qualifies as a different request, is it not?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code? Logging a user out? Or something more complicated?

Comment: Logging a user out. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getPageContext().getSession().invalidate() will invalidate the session, subsequent request with that sessionID will get an error trying to access the Session scope but the memory will not be reclaimed until the actual session timeout.

What you can do is session.setMaxInactiveInterval(int) set it to very a low number in ms so it expires right away and release the memory.  Then do a cflocation and for safe mesure use addToken="no"

Comment: Do you mean we should never use getPageContext().getSession().invalidate() ?

Comment: Yes and no, you can use it but it will only ensure that the session can't be used as you have noticed it is still very well alive and taking space until it actually timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Ben Nadel had series of posts related to "killing" session. As I remember it's not as easy as one method call. I'd google those.

Comment: +1 Ben has done some pretty interesting experiment with the session scope.

Comment: This one? http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1847-Explicitly-Ending-A-ColdFusion-Session.htm

Comment: I tried, but when the existing window refreshes, it will throw "Session is Invalid".  What shall I catch that and handle that gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of these for ur user logout function

1) Session.Remove(key)

2) Session(key) = nothing

Both are fine. But the later one is better if the user might want to re login or you actually....saves the effort of recreating a new key.

Comment: This is what I'm using currently, but I would like to use invalidate session for better security